# flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741795

Tags: android, ios, flutter, windows, dart

I getting The error when I running my project (flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741795)
And I Don't Know What is "Flutter.bat" I did flutter clean And flutter pub get And flutter upgrade and flutter pub upgrade --major-versions too but got same error Any one can help me

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.16.4 on channel stable at C:\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 2e9cb0aa71 (8 days ago), 2023-12-11 14:35:13 -0700
• Engine revision 54a7145303
• Dart version 3.2.3
• DevTools version 2.28.4

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
• All Android licenses accepted.

I thouth i installed flutter by wrong and i got same error